# Cannot locate symbol

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a native library ('processor') that I'm building with the Android NDK that depends on libjpeg.  This issue might be unrelated to the Android aspect however.  I've successfully built the library, but when I attempt to run the library fails to load properly with this error:

```
failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "jpeg_mem_src"
```

However if I `nm -D processor.so` it does indeed contain the symbols:

```
...
U jpeg_CreateCompress
U jpeg_CreateDecompress
U jpeg_destroy_compress
U jpeg_destroy_decompress
U jpeg_finish_compress
U jpeg_finish_decompress
U jpeg_mem_dest
U jpeg_mem_src
U jpeg_read_header
U jpeg_read_scanlines
...
```

processor build.gradle:

```
sources {
    main {
        jni {
            dependencies {
                project ":jpeg"
            }
        }
    }
}

ndk {
    moduleName "processor"
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
    ldLibs.add("log")
    stl "gnustl_shared"
}
```

The java side loads it with:

```
static
{
    try
    {
        Log.i("JNI", "Trying to load lib");
        System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
        System.loadLibrary("processor");
    }
    catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule)
    {
        Log.e("JNI", ule.toString());
    }
}
```

Any idea why the symbols exist, but can't be found?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on Android versions, you will have to load the jpeg library manually (and include it in your apk too !)

So just add a `System.loadLibrary("jpeg");` to your static block, and it should do the trick.

Btw, the fact that you can see the symbols in your `.so` file only means that your file is using them, not that your `.so` provides an implementation. You can see it as `nm` reports the symbols with the `U` letter, for `undefined`.

Comment: Ahh, thanks.  So if they're undefined 'U', then I may have done something wrong in generating the library?  (I have tried adding `System.loadLibrary("jpeg")`, but I get the same error, so it may be possible I'm generating all the libraries wrong for some reason)

Comment: In libjpeg.so:

000000000001dca0 T jpeg_mem_src

Comment: Your library depends on libjpeg (as said in your dependency block in the build.gradle file). It means that your library needs the `libjpeg.so` file to be loaded before it can be loaded itself. You can check this by running a `readelf -d` on your file, ti will show your all other needed shared libraries. You can safely ignore the libc, as it is always loaded by Android, but you must load the others manually.

Comment: Did you add the new `loadLibrary()` before your own ? Library loading order matters (load dependencies before libraries that use them), and Android won't do it for you.

Comment: I am currently loading jpeg before processor (but same error).  Thanks for the tip with readelf.  Looking into that now.